Conan per Project Repository configuration
I am looking for a Conan 2.x solution that is similiar to NPM's .npmrc which allows us to set registry=<private registry> and then commit that file into a git repository. NPM will honor that to resolve and upload packages, it also works with scopes.
What I have considered so far:

Do this setup in the Docker image. Caveat: it couples the registry details to the Docker image and reduces reusability, thus not a suitable solution.
Commit the remote.json into the repo and then move it into $CONAN_HOME, but this also does not feel right. Caveat: requires fiddling with files and $CONAN_HOME should be considered private to Conan.
Set it via the CI/CD pipeline using conan remote add/remove. Caveat: This requires two calls, one to remove conancenter and one to add the private registry. There is also no simple way to check if a registry was already added besides doing some custom parsing of the output of conan remote list or reading the CONAN_HOME/remotes.json file. If we accidentally call the registration logic more than once Conan will give an error because the registry was already added.

I am not sure if I am missing something. My preferred solution would be to just commit a .conanrc or similar file into the git repository, so that I just need to call conan login and start building / uploading packages.

To configure Conan client for developers and CI, the recommendation would be to use the conan config install. Haven't you considered this? It allows to put all configuration (profiles, custom settings, custom commands, custom plugins, etc), not only remotes definition in a git repo, http server or Conan package and install it from there. Is this what you are looking for?

You can get official responses and support directly from the maintainers submitting questions to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, it is also better to engage in conversations and feedback.
